# how to determine the order of being triggered of a event handler in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If more than one event handlers will response to one event, and the event handler callback function is defined in different places, how can i tell which handler will be triggered first, e.g.when checking `on/off` a `radio`, the `radio` binds several handlers, so how to tell which one will be executed first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript event handler order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143817/javascript-event-handler-order)

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706109/are-event-handlers-in-javascript-called-in-order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority when more than one event handler is bound to an element via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779657/priority-when-more-than-one-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-via-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript event handler order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143817/javascript-event-handler-order)

> If you use JQuery to bind your events, it guarantees that handlers are
>   fired in the same order that they were bound. Otherwise the order is
>   officially undefined.
>
> If you cannot use JQuery or a similar framework you can easily
>   simulate this by using your own custom even binding, where your
>   generic handler is a function which keeps an array of functions and
>   calls them in order.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation -
All handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the normal event propagation path.