# Does the capture option have any effect on the order of JS DOM event handling for listeners registered on the same element?

Tags: javascript

I am having a small problem with event handling order in JavaScript.

Supposed I have this:

```
targetElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething1, true)
targetElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething2, false)
```

Then doSomething1 will be called first then doSomething2.

But if I reverse them:

```
targetElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething2, false)
targetElement.addEventListener('click', doSomething1, true)
```

Then doSomething2 will get called first.

Does this mean, for target element, the third parameter is
meaningless? because it is in target phase? (I thought doSomething1
will always be called first since it sets capture phase to be true)

Comment: This may help: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143817/javascript-event-handler-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> Note: For event listeners attached to the event target; the event is in the target phase, rather than capturing and bubbling phases. Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element regardless of the useCapture parameter.

So yes, you are correct. For the target element, the third param has no effect.