# OnClick as well as listener is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to execute the function `getUser()` via an onclick event or a listener. I have already tried both, however, none of them is working.

Below you can find my code. How can I make it work?

I have already tried to use a button and an input instead of a div, not working as well. Not even the listeners if you use a button or an input instead of a div.

```js
$(document).on('focus', '#search_input', function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").show();
});

$(document).on('blur', '#search_input', function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").hide();
});


$(document).on('click', '.search-items', function() {
  console.log(this);
});

function getUser(id){
  console.log(id + "triggered");
}
```

```css
/* Autocomplete Stlying */

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  text-align: left;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="search_input_wrapper" class="autocomplete form-group" style="margin: 0px">
    <input id="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Kunde" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div id="autocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items" style="display: none;">
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(2)">2: Max, Mustermann</div>
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(3)">3: Tom, Maier</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: I don't get any errors

Comment: Is not working as well without the `.autocomplete-items`

Comment: Some more helpful notes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779657/priority-when-more-than-one-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) on input and the list elements like so:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '#search_input', function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").show();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").hide();
});

$("#autocomplete-list, #search_input_wrapper").on('click', function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
});


function getUser(id) {
  console.log(id + "triggered");
}
```

```css
/* Autocomplete Stlying */

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  text-align: left;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="search_input_wrapper" class="autocomplete form-group" style="margin: 0px">
    <input id="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Kunde" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div id="autocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items" style="display: none;">
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(2)">2: Max, Mustermann</div>
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(3)">3: Tom, Maier</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. What exactly is stopPropagation doing and why do I need this?

Comment: when you say close list on document click, the list itself is part of document. you need to tell the javascript on click everywhere but the list close that. see this : https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get you and I also don't really understand the documentation..

Comment: @Jan The event that hides the dropdown is attached to the whole document, including `.search-items`. Because that is attached *frirst*, it happens before the click event on the `.search-items` themselves. This event does not fire because the elements are now hidden. You can use `stopPropogation` on `.search-items` to restrict it from firing the `document` click event.

Comment: tanx @TylerRoper :D

Answer (score 2):

stopPropagation stops event bubbling up the DOM tree. In other terms, when you click on `search-items` the default javascript behavior is to trigger the click on the clicked element parents/grandparents as well.

So when you click on `search-items` it would trigger click on `#search-input`. And so, the opened list closes. With `stopPropagation()` you dismiss this behavior and tell javascript that the click event should only be listened on the clicked element.

In the below code, `e` is short for `event` which, in your case, is the `click` event.

I made some minor changes to your code but you can still use `blur` and `focus`. There are many ways to re-write this code but the important thing is to `stopPropagation`

```js
// changed to click and toggle() to show hide the list
// but you can keep the blur and focus if you like

$(document).on('click', '#search_input', function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").toggle();
});

$(document).on('click', '.search-items', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation() 
  getUser(e.target.id) 
  // event = click, target = .search-items, id = the id of the clicked target
  // just pass the id to to your getUser function
});

function getUser(id) {
console.log(`user has id ${id}`)
// concatenate strings using new Template Literals
}
```

```css
/* Autocomplete Stlying */

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  text-align: left;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="search_input_wrapper" class="autocomplete form-group" style="margin: 0px">
    <input id="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Kunde" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div id="autocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items" style="display: none;">
      <div class="search-items" id="2">2: Max, Mustermann</div>
      <div class="search-items" id="3">3: Tom, Maier</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

And [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and
>   bubbling phases.

If you have any questions, just ask in the comments below

Answer (score -1):

Using `stopPropagation` is not necessary.

Your .blur (the first event to happen) prevents  a .click on the menu, because it hides it before you even get to click on it. You could add a delay to the to the menu hide, or detect when a user is hovering on an item before hiding it. But now you get into the case where a user is hovering, but presses tab or loses focus some other way, so you'd have to handle that.

```js
var focusedOnSearchItem = false;
$('.search-items').click(function() {
  // console.log('search-items click()',this);
  $("#autocomplete-list").hide();
});
$('.search-items').mouseenter(function() {
  focusedOnSearchItem = true;
});
$('.search-items').mouseleave(function() {
  focusedOnSearchItem = false;
});

$('#search_input').focus(function() {
  $("#autocomplete-list").show();
});

$('#search_input').blur(function(event) {
  if(!focusedOnSearchItem)
    $("#autocomplete-list").hide();
});

function getUser(id){
  console.log(id + "triggered");
}
```

```css
/* Autocomplete Stlying */

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  text-align: left;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="search_input_wrapper" class="autocomplete form-group" style="margin: 0px">
    <input id="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Kunde" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <div id="autocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items" style="display: none;">
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(2)">2: Max, Mustermann</div>
      <div class="search-items" onclick="getUser(3)">3: Tom, Maier</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```