# An order of triggered events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

There is a `<div>` with two classes. For every class there is a triggered event on click, separate event for every class. Is there a way to make sure that the event for class `class_one` always will be triggered first and always `console.log("First")` will be fired first.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.class_one', function() {
  console.log("First")
})

$('body').on('click', '.class_two', function() {
  console.log("Second")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class_one class_two">Click me</div>
```

Comment: I believe [jQuery events are handled in the order they are bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2360655/519413), although I haven't personally tested it to determine how reliable this is.

Comment: In different places of the code they are bound in a different order. I need to be 100% sure that in any place it will be fired in that order that I need. Is there a way to manage orders of triggered events in vanilla JS without jquery?

Comment: Then I don't believe you can. If you start a new question which expands on the reason why you need this we may be able to suggest alternatives, as relying on the order of event execution is not a good thing to be doing.

Comment: execute one event and in that event callback call the other fuction

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   ah...ok, I think it will be a too wide a question for SO, so I will try to find workarounds by myself. Thanks ;)

Comment: @brk it is a good suggestion but the example is very simplified. Let's assume that in real code I have access only to code of the first event handler function and html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority when more than one event handler is bound to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779657/priority-when-more-than-one-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events are not triggered on classes, the are triggered on elements. If the classes "class_one" and "class_two" are set on the same element then events are called in the same order they where bound. However events bubble up, meaning the "click" event is first triggered on element clicked, then its parent and so forth.

This means if you have the ability to change the DOM, you can force the events on the element with class "class_one" to be fired first. This can be done by removing the "class_two" class from the element and wrapping it around the "class_one" element.

This behaviour is can be found described in the jQuery [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation:

> When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as *delegated*. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.class_one', function() {
  console.log("First")
})

$('body').on('click', '.class_two', function() {
  console.log("Second")
})

$('body').on('click', '.class_one', function() {
  console.log("Third")
})

$('body').on('click', '.class_two', function() {
  console.log("Fourth")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class_two">
  <div class="class_one">Click me</div>
</div>
```

---

Like already said above: If the classes "class_one" and "class_two" are set on the same element then events are called in the same order they where bound.

Which can also be also found in the [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation:

> Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.

This property could be used to register two events that act as a "register" and fire all events added to this "register" (a simple array in the example).

This solution doesn't require you to change the DOM, but instead requires you to change the event registration in JavaScript.

```js
const class_one_click_fns = [],
      class_two_click_fns = [];

$('body').on('click', '.class_one', function(...args) {
  class_one_click_fns.forEach(fn => fn.call(this, ...args))
})

$('body').on('click', '.class_two', function(...args) {
  class_two_click_fns.forEach(fn => fn.call(this, ...args))
})

class_one_click_fns.push(function () {
  console.log("First")
})

class_two_click_fns.push(function () {
  console.log("Second")
})

class_one_click_fns.push(function () {
  console.log("Third")
})

class_two_click_fns.push(function () {
  console.log("Fourth")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class_one class_two">Click me</div>
```

Comment: is this described somewhere in jQuery documentation or code? Your answer sounds very reasonable, but there should be some spec/code that governs this - to be 100% sure creators of jQuery implemented this the same way we think it should be done.

Comment: @zmii I've added a documentation reference, to support the answer.

Comment: Hey, @3limin4t0r!
Thanks for your answer. It is very clear, deep, and useful. The first approach is more than perfect suitable for my current situation. I tested and it works great.